# Отображение данных mqtt клиентом в Label в реальном времени

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, mqtt

Есть два куска кода. Первый подписывается на топик MQTT-сервера и получает значение. Второй - интерфейс Tkinter. Вопрос, как заставить программу менять текст Label в реальном времени, то есть записывать в него полученное значение?

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    #print("Connected with result code: " +str(rc))
    client.subscribe("/test/nfc")


def on_message (client, userdata, msg):
    global teacher
    #print(str(msg.topic),str(msg.payload))
    teacher=str(msg.payload)
client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect("сервер", порт, 60)
client.username_pw_set("логин","пароль")
client.loop_forever()
```

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Карта")
root.geometry("1600x900")
root.configure(bg="white")
text1 = Label(root, text="1", bg='white', font='Times 20')
text1.grid(row=0, column=3)
text2 = Label(root, text=teacher, bg='white', font='Times 20')
text2.grid(row=0, column=4)
root.mainloop()
```

Собственно, как эти два куска объединить, чтоб text2 отображал значение teacher в реальном времени? Я так понимаю, что проблема объединения заключается в том, что и 1 и 2 кусок кода должны быть зациклены. Если их запихать в один код (как есть), то получается, что работает либо одно, либо другое.

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае вместо блокирующего `client.loop_forever()` (бесконечного цикла по сути) нужно делать периодический вызов `client.loop()`, который проверяет наличие сообщений и сразу завершается (см. [Network loop](https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/#network-loop)). Периодические действия в tkinter реализуются с помощью метода `after`:

```
from tkinter import *
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    #print("Connected with result code: " +str(rc))
    client.subscribe("/test/nfc")


def on_message (client, userdata, msg):
    #print(str(msg.topic),str(msg.payload))
    teacher=str(msg.payload)
    text2['text'] = teacher


def init_mqtt():
    client = mqtt.Client()
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_message = on_message
    client.connect("сервер", 1234, 60)
    client.username_pw_set("логин","пароль")
    return client


def mqtt_loop(client):
    client.loop(timeout=0.1)  # ждать не дольше 0.1 секунд
    # Запланировать следующий запуск mqtt_loop через 50 миллисекунд:
    root.after(50, mqtt_client, client)


root = Tk()
root.title("Карта")
root.geometry("1600x900")
root.configure(bg="white")
text1 = Label(root, text="1", bg='white', font='Times 20')
text1.grid(row=0, column=3)
text2 = Label(root, text="", bg='white', font='Times 20')
text2.grid(row=0, column=4)

mqtt_client = init_mqtt()
mqtt_loop(mqtt_client)

root.mainloop()
```